# How to prevent/close duplicate tabs in Safari?

Tags: browser-addons, plugins, safari, tabs, duplicate

I have an extension for [Firefox, "Close Repeated Tabs"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/close-repeated-tabs/), and one for [Chrome called "Tab Dupectomy"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nkkedbpcfdogedipgdhgeknjdphaplbk)...  but I really use Safari the most, and often have HUNDREDS of tabs open.  I am **desperate** for a way to close, or ideally prevent from opening altogether - each tab that is for the SAME URL as another.  I would imagine this is possible via an extension, script, etc.

PLEASE HELP!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any extension that achieves this, but (9 years after question was asked), Safari does have built-in tab sorting in the Window menu ("Arrange tabs by"). So, that might be a good-enough solution. First sort tabs by "Website", then it's easier to go through them with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and remove duplicates.